# If you upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013, does the licence from the prior version carry over?

Tags: .net, tfs, licensing

We want to upgrade our source control from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013. Do we need a new license for the upgrade or does the TFS 2010 license carry over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your server is covered by an active MSDN subscription, you will need to buy a new license for the TFS Server.

You will also need to purchase new Client Access Licenses in case your users are not using an MSDN subscription.

Comment: Unfortunately, the client does not have a MSDN subscription. I guess we are out of luck.